# Network burden of RPi Cam Web Interface

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, camera

I'm wondering about [streaming a Raspberry camera's output](https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi_projects/blog/2016/04/25/noir-v2-video-streaming-baby-monitor#comment-91293) over the local network using [RPi Cam Web Interface](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) suite.  I have a concern about the burden on wifi network bandwidth. Can anyone advise if this approach would take up network bandwidth even when nothing is connected, or would this only happen when someone is actively streaming?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it only uses network bandwidth when some is visiting the web site to see the camera image as the camera is connect directly to the rpi via a direct interface.

The impact should not be significant to your (home?) wifi network.

The most important part is *if that site is available to the Internet at large*, care must be taken to protect it with a login/password.

Comment: Thanks Rui. That was my thinking, but good to have it checked by someone with more network knowledge than me.